# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' - PHP 5.3.29

Tags: php, array, sintaxe

Tenho uma aplicação rodando certinho localmente.
Porém quando joguei ela on-line fico recebendo a seguinte mensagem e não tenho nenhum retorno dos dados.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/relatorios.intercol.com.br/_app/Models/RelatorioOs.class.php on line 118

Minha versão do PHP é a 5.3.29

e o código em questão seria.

```
private function _getTipoOs(int $codostipo){
       $tipoOS = new Read();
       $tipoOS->ExeRead($this->empresa, 'mk_os_tipo', 'WHERE codostipo = :cot', "cot={$codostipo}", "descricao");
       $this->result = $tipoOS->getResult()[0];
       return $this->result["descricao"];
    }
```

agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Comment: O php5.3 não suporta essa tipo de sintaxe `$tipoOS->getResult()[0];` precisa guardar o retorno da função em uma variável e depois utilizar o indice zero `$var[0]`

Comment: Também não é possível tipar os parâmetros com tipos primitivos, precisa remover ele da assinatura. `_getTipoOs(int $codostipo)`

Comment: Vamo usa php >= 7 pessoal kkkkkkk..!

Comment: Drik, se fosse por mim ja estariamos usando mesmo.
a syntax era isso mesmo e ja me adiantei e removi o int $codostipo.
obrigado pelo ajuda pessoal.